# Converting htaccess to nginx for counter

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I used to have my site hosted on a Apache server and had my htaccess file like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^debs_public/(.*)\.deb$ counter.php?request=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
```

I recently changed to a VPS and set the server up using nginx as per recommendations of it being faster. I've been struggling with the conversion of the htaccess file. I used a converter and got this line.

```
location /debs_public {
rewrite ^/debs_public/(.*)\.deb$ /counter.php?request=$request_filename;
}
```

but when I add this to my configuration it results in error 500 internal server error. Any suggestions as to what to change?

Note: What the counter does is count when a deb is downloaded from my Cydia repository. Works fine in  Apache but fails in nginx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
location /debs_public/ {
   rewrite ^/debs_public/(.*)\.deb$ counter.php?request=$request_filename; break;
   return  403;
}
```

Hopefully this may work.

Special Quote:

"if these directives are put inside the “/debs_public/” location, the last flag should be replaced by break, or otherwise nginx will make 10 cycles and return the 500 error:"

Refrence: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: This got rid of the 500 error but I receive 404 error now. I might have to update my php to work with this new setup.

Comment: Yes, now you will need to see if the requested file name does exist in your application because as you said the redirection now seems to be working. Now at least you can play with it as the issue might be the file name non existence. You can still share more info to me regarding the URL etc so that i can think if i can help you for this also. :)